# GAE PHP - Error page displays locally but not when deployed

Tags: php, google-app-engine

When serving locally (via app engine launcher) the error.html page displays, but when deployed it doesn't resolve to the error page when I receive a 404/etc response.

I deployed new versions and it didn't help too. Is there anything wrong with my YAML file or does anyone have any other suggestions?

Thanks

YAML file

```
application: xxxmeowxxx
version: 1-5
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
# Serve as static resources.
- url: /img
  static_dir: img
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
- url: /fonts
  static_dir: fonts
- url: /Documents
  static_dir: Documents


# Serve php scripts
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

#serve php scripts without needing .php
- url: /(.+)
  script: \1.php

#serve index 
- url: /
  script: index.php

#Error handle
error_handlers:
  - file: error.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the best way to handle errors is the create a router. You would include a catch all in your yaml (this would go after everything else you are declaring in the yaml file) and handle all requests within your router file.

YAML

```
#serve router
- url: /(.*)
script: /routes.php
```

Router file

```
$path       = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH); //get full path
```

Answer (score 1):

The only error types supported are

- over_quota, which indicates the app has exceeded a resource quota;
- dos_api_denial, which is served to any client blocked by your app's DoS Protection configuration;
- timeout, served if a deadline is reached before there is a response from your app.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Custom_error_responses for more details.

To have an error page for 404, simply add a catch-all handler (/.*) after your index.php to print out the content.

Comment: Thanks but, this isn't the issue. My YAML and error catching works locally but when deployed it doesn't work. I have figured out it has to do with the -> url: /(.+) within the YAML file. This is the portion that doesn't allow the error page to be displayed when deployed but again works locally.